# Just finished Highschool and I am starting my degree in math after the summer, but in the mean time what subjects should I try and study?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education, book-recommendation, advice

Hi I just finished Highschool, I'm starting a degree in math when the summer is over but I want to do a bit of self-studying just for fun. As you might expect I am not very knowledgeable of college level mathematics and do not know what subjects I should study. To give you a better idea of my level I have in my free time finished going through Calculus Early Trancendentals By James Stewart. This is (I think) Calc 1 2 and 3 (they did however start omitting alot of proofs at the calc 3 section). This book wasn't insanely difficult for me but it also wasn't a walk in the park (which is to be expected when learing something new). I have also completed highschool mathematics with a 9.8 (we here use grades from 1 to 10 where 10 is perfect and 1 is nothing correct).

What subjects should I now study, could you also explain in short what the subject studies and do you have any good book recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you'll come back here after the summer to tell us what you did, and how it worked for you.

Comment: Ok. I'm not completely sure as to what I will read but Recreations in Number theory sounds really fun. I'm also probaly going to try and study a more typical subject like Analysis or Algebra but I'm still looking for good books in one of those subjects.

Comment: OK. Your question has the tag, book-recommendation. If you click on that tag, it will show you some of the 2600 other questions (!) with that tag. I expect you'll find some of them were asking for recommendations for Analysis and/or Algebra textbooks, and you may find some of the answers helpful. Also, see https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews

Answer (score 1):

Did you got the curriculum of your major(/track if your college have) and know what you must study to get the degree? Anyway, I believe Cal 3 (as you mentioned, inc. partial derivatives, line integrals, vector fields, Green's/Stokes' Thm, etc), linear algebra (sth like eigenvalues/vectors, span, rank, etc) and analysis (more proper/vigorous definitions on calculus, infinite sequences, metric spaces, etc) are a must.

So for these 3 areas of study, Stewart's multi-cal textbook or [Paul's online math notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/calciii.aspx) would still be a feasible choice for Cal 3. As for lin alg and analysis, I relied on lecture notes pretty much and don't have a good idea for the course materials. Maybe you can find the past exams papers and have a peek on what you will be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read something fun, something you're not likely to see in the undergraduate curriculum. Ian Stewart, [Another](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/626957.Another_Fine_Math_You_ve_Got_Me_Into) Fine Math You've Got Me Into, or Albert Beiler, [Recreations](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/recreations-in-the-theory-of-numbers) in the Theory of Numbers, or pretty nearly anything by Martin [Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gardner). Or Imre Lakatos, [Proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_and_Refutations) and Refutations.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a reference for study but I highly recommend that you take time to organize your day and take time for self care; exercising, meal planning, taking time for yourself. I am very happy you are excited for college, but understand it is a marathon and not just a sprint. You want to build healthy habits now as a freshman because you will struggle in upper level courses. When you struggle, it is important that you have set up strong and good habits to take a break from work before trying again. College takes a lot of work, recovering between challenges is super important to your long term success.

But if you really want something to play with I recommend *Linear Algebra and its Applications* ([https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-5th/dp/032198238X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032198238X))